# Getting the StackTrace from original uncaughtException

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, android-asynctask, stack-trace

I'm trying to get the AndroidRuntime Exception StackTrace same as Logcat. However, when I Override the uncaughtException of UncaughtExceptionHandler, it gives me a different StackTrace other than the LogCat one. Here is my code:

```
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler aovUncaughtExceptionHandler = 
    new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            StackTraceElement stackTrace[] = thread.getStackTrace();
            int stackTraceLength=stackTrace.length;
            String exceptionDescription = "";
            for (int i=0; i<stackTraceLength; i++) {
                exceptionDescription = exceptionDescription + stackTrace[i];
            }
            setException(exceptionDescription,true);
            applicationExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread,ex);
        }
    };

public AovGaTracker() {
    applicationExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(aovUncaughtExceptionHandler);
}
```

Here is the Stacktrace when using Exception as a stacktrace source:

```
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the stackTrace when using Thread as a stackTace source:

```
dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:579)
com.example.googleanalytics.AovGaTracker$1.uncaughtException(AovGaTracker.java:28)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the supposed to be StackTrace from Logcat (which is what I need):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 18207
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
... 11 more
```

Is there anyway that I can execute getting the `stacktrace` after `uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)` is executed? Do I need to use asynctask? Do I need to program asynctask on the same thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always only one uncaught exception depending on the location of the exception set during runtime.

The exception in log cat is a combination of the stack trace, and the cause of the exception. You can combine exception.getStackTrace() and exception.getCause() to get the same result as logcat.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world `DefaultExceptionHandler` works like a charm for me throughout application. Where it causes unhandled  Exception it triggers up.

Library named [Android-Remote-StackTrace](https://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/source/browse/src/com/nullwire/trace/DefaultExceptionHandler.java?r=0ef73a0079f5c8d26d377e9a96996fff2f569016).  You just need to register the broadcast of these DefaultHandlerException class in your Application class.

Snippet:

```
 public class Portfolio extends Application {
 static Portfolio portfolio;
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    portfolio = this;
    ExceptionHandler.register(portfolio);// registering for unhandled Exceptions
   }
 }
```

You can do various task with these such as uploading the log stack trace to your server or send mails on the crash of application as a Crash Report with your unhandled Stack Trace.

Comment: I saw the codes for getting the UncaughtException, and it gets the stack trace from logcat file. However, is there anyway to catch the exception while the app is running... say using AndroidRuntimeException()?